# What is the the best way to convert JSONObject to a domain object?

Tags: java, json, restlet

I have a rest service returning some data. I use Restlet client api as shown below to access this service. As you can see, it returns org.json.JSONObject. Is there a easy way to map this to the domain object (may be through annotations?) or should I have to write code to create the domain object?

```
Representation entity = new ClientResource(uri).get();
JSONObject json = new JsonRepresentation(entity).getJsonObject();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can leverage from [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library which has a function you need:

```
// Convert JSON into Java object    
SomeObj obj = gson.fromJson(jsonObjStr, SomeObj.class)
```

You can read more [here...](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Answer (score 1):

While there are decent APIs for easily mapping between Java data structures, e.g., from the JSONObject to your preferred data structure, since the incoming data format is JSON, I'd much prefer to just use a good JSON-to/from-Java API like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).  Depending on the preferred transformation details, the solution might be just one simple line of code with such an API.